# Honda accord 2008 vibrates intermittently while driving

Tags: honda, accord, shaking

I noticed recently that my Honda vibrates at low speeds/when you DON'T step hard on the throttle pedal. It doesn't do this every time and I have had my wheel balancing done and checked my engine seating. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Diesel or petrol ?

Comment: @watsche, it's a petrol engine

Comment: OK, then I would look at engine suspension, silent block. Then try rear wheel to front.

Answer (score 1):

Engine/gearbox mountings may be worn. Ignition coil(s) starting to fail. Accelerator pedal position sensor starting to wear. Fuel injector intermittant fault. There are many reasons more, so a check over at your repair shop would be recommended.